Matlab Path optimization algorithm
Follow up of a previous question to avoid confusion.
I am developing a code to find the best paths in a complex graph. I want to find a set of paths ( path definition: a list of vertices with 2 or more members, where each successive vertex pair in the list is connected by an edge ) which covers every edge exactly once, and of all such possible sets you want to select the one that has the longest paths and the fewest paths with just one edge.
Following @ravenspoint suggestion, I have implemented a slightly modified version of the Prim's algorithm. In particular:

starting from a vertex I select the minimum edge weight neighbor. Weights are cartesian distances between vertices. For each new vertex I add the relative [starting_vertex, new_vertex] edge to a list of visited;
when at least 2 vertices are in the path, I consider both first and last vertex to continue the search
when the path is completed I check for completed vertices.

I have iterated this code on my vertices list, changing for each iteration their order. In the end I get n paths, where n is the total number of vertices.
I was thinking about choosing the best iteration like this:
for each iteration

- select the 1-Edge paths 
- measure their weight (aka length)
- pick the minimum

end

of all these minimums, I pick the iteration with the longest one. Also, since my selection is based on the minimum edge weight (see point one of my approach), there is a higher chance that 1-Edge paths will have high weight (i.e., length).
However, the number of 1-edge paths is similar to what I was getting before (ca. 30% of the total number of edges). I was hoping to minimize this number even more.

"select the one that has the longest paths and the fewest paths with just one edge"  What is the trade-off function?  Which is better, a path set with one path length 10 and 10 paths of length 1 or a path set with one path length 5 and 5 paths of length 1?

My theory for now would be what I wrote at the end of my post, from "I was thinking about choosing the best iteration like this:" on. Anyhow, it would be actual-length dependent.

"select the 1-Edge paths "  Your choice algorithm ignores all paths longer than 1 edge.  But in your 2nd paragraph you wrote " select the one that has the longest paths "  Which is it?  ( Note: I haves asked this question several times now.  I will not ask again.  If you do not provide a real answer then your question is meaningless )

To clarify:  there are numerous ways of generating candidate path sets.  Without a well specified function to be optimized, there is no way to choose the "best" set.  So there is no way to evaluate the competing path set generators for the most effective.

I use the approach I put in the question as a first selection for the best iteration (meaning, sorted nodes array). I am still in the process of developing a nice scoring system, also following the suggestion you gave me in the previous post and implementing a real-length score, in which also 1-edge path, if long enough, will not be penalized as shorter ones. However, my question is not meaningless, because my main point is not the selection of the best iteration, but a way to reduce the number of 1-Edge paths.

"I am still in the process of developing a nice scoring system"  Let us know when you have that.  This should be the FIRST thing you design, since everything else follow from this.  Until you know what it is that your are optimizing, you cannot design an optimizing algorithm.  Designing an algorithm to ONLY minimize the number of 1-edge paths is known as 'barking up the wrong tree'.
